# stop function call in frida-trace onEnter

Tags: ios, frida

I am playing around with `frida`, specifically `frida-trace` on iOS.

When a method is hooked and I can log the params in `onEnter`, is there a way I can make this function call end early and not call the original method?

I've tried adding `return;` to the `onEnter` method, however `onLeave` is still called and the methods in between are called.

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same question so asked it on [Github](https://github.com/frida/frida/issues/485), and here is oleavr's answer:

> No, that would require Interceptor to know the function's calling convention and signature, e.g. for stdcall. Use Interceptor.replace() instead.

To learn more about Interceptor.replace(), you can look up the [official documentation](https://www.frida.re/docs/javascript-api/#interceptor), but pretty much as the name says, you can replace the original function with your own implementation:

```
var openPtr = Module.findExportByName("libc.so", "open");
var open = new NativeFunction(openPtr, 'int', ['pointer', 'int']);
Interceptor.replace(openPtr, new NativeCallback(function (pathPtr, flags) {
    var path = Memory.readUtf8String(pathPtr);
    log("Opening '" + path + "'");
    var fd = open(pathPtr, flags);
    log("Got fd: " + fd);
    return fd;
}, 'int', ['pointer', 'int']));
```

(Example from the docs.)